# MVC5 displaying formatted div for each row?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a VB Razor page which loops though the model's collection of listings as shown

```
    @<div class="mini-listing">
         @Html.ActionLink(listing.SaleName, "Listing", New With {.id = listing.ID.ToString}, New With {.class = "mini-listing-title"})
         <span class="mini-listing-location">@listing.City, @listing.State</span>
         <span class="mini-listing-created">Posted - @listing.CreatedOn.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")</span>
         <span class="mini-listing-description">"@listing.SaleDescription"</span>
    </div>
```

I want to take this exact div structure and use it in a WebGrid instead so I can take advantage of the pagentation. So it would be a Webgrid with a single column which has the above div once per row.

I am completely lost with syntax errors and function errors as most of the online help is for C#. Do I have to write a helper function that separately renders the div which I pass the model to?

For example do I have to do something like this? I wanted to keep as much formatting on the same Razor view as possible however.

```
@Code
    Dim gridListing As New WebGrid(Model.Listings)
    Dim cols As New List(Of WebGridColumn)
    cols.Add(gridListing.Column(format:=Function(item) Helpers.ListingDiv(item))

End code

@gridListing.GetHtml(columns:=cols,htmlAttributes:=New With {.id = "listing-schedule"})
```

**Edit -Partial View Solution?**

Is this an acceptable approach to solve this?

```
@Code
    Dim gridListing As New WebGrid(Model.Listings)
    Dim cols As New List(Of WebGridColumn)
    cols.Add(gridListing.Column(format:=Function(item) Html.Partial("~/Views/Sale/_minilisting.vbhtml", New ViewModels.SaleListingMinimal With {
                                                                    .City = item.City,
                                                                    .SaleDescription = item.SaleDescription,
                                                                    .SaleName = item.SaleName}
                                                                     )))

End code

@gridListing.GetHtml(columns:=cols,htmlAttributes:=New With {.id = "listing-schedule"})
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894313/mvc3-webgrid-custom-text-in-column) uses VB for generating custom html in a WebGrid column

Comment: Thanks. I will look at that one. I just made an edit to show code using a partial view. Is what I just added also a feasible answer? I tested it and it does work.